# How to copy an ArrayList that cannot be influenced by the original ArrayList changes?

Tags: java, arraylist, cloning

I've been using ArrayLists on a project of mine, and I need to create a default ArrayList so I can reset the original one whenever I want. So, I copy the original ArrayList to create the default one. However, whenever I modify something on the original, it also changes the default one. How can I make the copy "static" and unchangeable?

Here is my code: (It's in portuguese)

```
private ArrayList<Compartimento> listaCompartimentos;
private ArrayList<Compartimento> listaCompartimentosDEFAULT;

public Simulador() {
        this.listaCompartimentos = new ArrayList<>();
        this.listaCompartimentosDEFAULT=new ArrayList<>();
    }

//Copy of the array
public void gravarListaDefault(){
        this.listaCompartimentosDEFAULT=(ArrayList<Compartimento>)listaCompartimentos.clone();
    }
```

Note: I don't know if it can be the reason behind it, but the ArrayList listaCompartimentos has a listaEquipamentos. For each "Compartimento" there is an ArrayList "listaEquipamentos".

Comment: I don't think you should use the clone there. Not a Java expert, but i think a simple assignment would work.

Comment: @Gjordis you are right ; ) (about cloning)

Comment: @Gjordis simple assignment won't work in Java.

Comment: Ok assign by constructor then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**`clone()`** for `ArrayLists` should be avoided because even if it creates a **new `List` instance**, it holds references to the **same elements**. So an element changed on the first `List` will also be changed on the second one. *Two different objects holding the same references.*

The code below will create a new instance with new elements.

```
ArrayList<Object> realClone = new ArrayList<Object>();
for(Object o : originalList)
   realClone.add(o.clone());
```

Comment: @AsierAranbarri Cloning does create a shallow copy. It says in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#clone%28%29)

Comment: The thing is: In my main class, using the respective object that contains these two ArrayLists, I fill the original one, only THEN I clone it. These two ArrayList both belong to the class "Simulador" so, you are telling me to create two "Simulador" if I have to use a copy-constructor?

Comment: You have to. When you clone a list, you are creating a new list but NOT new elements.

Comment: Seems like `new ArrayList(originalList)` also creates a shallow copy, with references identical to `originalList`.

Answer (score 2):

```
this.listaCompartimentosDEFAULT = new ArrayList<Compartimento>(
            listaCompartimentos);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to `clone` each object . Make your `Compartimento`class implements [Cloneable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html). And clone each object in the `List` and add to the other `List`.

```
for(Compartimento c : this.listaCompartimentos) {
    this.listaCompartimentosDEFAULT.add(c.clone());
}
```

Comment: that's in my answer as well ; ). +1